# https links using rufuse scheduler - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rufus-scheduler

My site is working with `https` protocol. When I am creating a link in an email. It is creating a link with `http` protocol. My other links are being created correctly but link with created in `rufuse` scheduler's schedule is getting `http`. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain how (code) you create the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:protocol` option in a `link_to` (which I'm assuming you are using).

```
<%= link_to "Click here", root_url(:protocol => "https") %>
```